# Syncing content in Multisite. Possible?

Tags: multisite

I'm looking to setup Multisite and use the second site to show the same exact pages, accessing the same posts, and excluding those pages with a custom field that reads something like "Parent site only".

Any idea on how to go about this?

Comment: Unfortunately, both Answers point to a [dead plugin](http://web.archive.org/web/20110722095739/http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/multipost-mu/) :( . . . This is what one of the [authors said in May 2012](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/plugin-multipost-mu-wp-331): " *This plugin hasn't been updated in some time and is actually slated to be removed from the Plugin Directory. Sadly, I have no time to support the plugin and I don't want people risk potential security issues moving forward.* "...

Answer (score 1):

WP ebooks has a plugin called [WP Multisite Replicator](http://wpebooks.com/replicator/) that doesn't keep things in sync but it does let you replicate sites one-off.